# Azure AD B2C: Unable to get token with authorization code

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am currently following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code) guide on setting up authorization for an azure function. I'm currently trying to test the auth portion in fiddler separately from my web app to ensure I can get a valid token. I am able to successfully retrieve an authorization code however after that, I need to post some data to exchange the authorization code for a token. When trying to do that, I am being returned a 502 with message: `DNS Lookup for "mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No such host is known`  as if the host does not exist at all. My post to the endpoint looks as follows where `B2C_1_FunctionsPlaygroundSignInRegister` is the name of my user flow:

```
POST https://mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1_FunctionsPlaygroundSignInRegister HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Fiddler

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Host: mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com

Body:grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=MyApplicationIdForTheAzure-AD-B2C-ap-here&code=myCodeHere&redirect_uri=jwt.ms
```

For reference, here is the working get request I send that I can type in a browser, be prompted with a login/register screen, and be returned an authorization code after logging in:

```
https://mytenantname.b2clogin.com/tfp/mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_FunctionsPlaygroundSignInRegister/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=yApplicationIdForTheAzure-AD-B2C-ap-here&nonce=2&redirect_uri=https://functionapi.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback&scope=https://mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com/api/read&response_type=code
```

Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong here? I've now spent a great deal of time on this issue and am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST url and Host header are wrong.

See this section -

#### [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code#2-get-a-token)

```
POST fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_sign_in HTTP/1.1
Host: https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com
```

Note the Host header. That means your Fiddler request should read something like this:

```
POST https://mytenantname.b2clogin.com/mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=...
Host: mytenantname.b2clogin.com
```

P.S. This is way better than Fiddler for what you're trying to do -
https://oauthdebugger.com/

Comment: Ah as many times as I've read that article, I missed this. Thanks. Now it looks like I need to provide a client secret (I'm assuming this secret is set up on the function app and not the azure ad application) but you've solved the issue at hand. Will accept when possible

Comment: It's the secret (aka _key_) under your app definition in Azure AD B2C.